# Load Images from subDomain/Other Domain in C#

Tags: c#, iis

I have a website(www.mydomain.com) which has admin panel(admin.mydomain.com). All images I uploaded through admin panel are stored in sub-domain(admin.subdomain/Content/Images/image1.jpg).

Now I need to load these images in my website, for that I have option to assign image's url as src = "admin.subdomain/Content/Images/image1.jpg".

My question is, will it cause performance problem to load images through url rather than giving Image path, if not then I'll go with it, if yes then how to overcome this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that will affect performance:

1. Sending out the a full domain to the browser will be sending more bytes. It's the difference between `/images/whatever.jpg` and `http://admin.somedomain.com/images/whatever.jpg`. However, this is such a tiny difference, you would need to be running at massive scale to notice any difference on your bandwidth, and certainly a client wouldn't see any difference.
2. Browsers will only open a limited number of connections to the same domain. This means if you host Javascript files, images, CSS etc. on the same server, the browser will queue up those requests. So hosting your images on another domain allows the browser to download them at the same time, making the whole process faster. That's why many sites will use a CDN to host their resources. For example, take a look at this site. Even the logo is hosted on `cdn.sstatic.net`